Am I missing something in running a process in FastAPI with uvicorn?
When I run this code locally:
import subprocess

print('before')
subprocess.run(['python', 'target_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])
print('after')

Output:
before
after

But when I run the same code in FastAPI...
from fastapi import FastAPI
import subprocess

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
def index():
    subprocess.run(['python', 'target_script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from uvicorn import run
    run(app, port=80)

Output: (when I start the app)
INFO:     Started server process [3568]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

Output: (when I enter the index page)
INFO:     Started server process [3568]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

I want the process to not be related with uvicorn process.
What should I do?

can't understand what you want. you should be more clear and verbose. otherwise in future you can't ask questions on Stackoverflow they'll limit you

I'm sorry for the confusen but as I said, looks like that subprocess is affected by FastAPI. Is it true? If yes, how can I fix it? Sorry again for any confusen

What do you mean with affected? What is happening? What do you want to happen instead?

What does Output: (when I enter the index page) mean? Looks like you are running server in different way in this case (not just run .py file)

I don't understand? It's just a web server and I enter the main page. The problem is that when I run a process using subprocess module, I'm getting logs from uvicorn but I don't want uvicorn know when I run my process using subprocess.

see I understand now your problem. but unfortunately, it is not possible. as it is the default behaviour, I can say it because when I use streamlit for projects it also gives me a link like uvicorn do but whatever I do in the application is printed in the console but don't worry nothing will happen

you are safe but don't use system calls if it is a public facing API. if it is blocking your main thread somehow just use subprocess.Popen
